# how to i fix my firebase rule issue which always getting false condition?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My issue is that In my firebase database i want to access write in categories child only for admins and I have all the admins listed in the "ADMIN" child of my root. and inside admin child I stored all the users info with the child of their uids; Like this:

```js
       root
         |
         |--ADMIN
         |   |
         |   |--Hu1QtgYoL4SF3nUFdTcrTamCdfb2
         |                |
         |                |-- id: "84bvMZRKbutMZh5zBwxaRZdA9mVI1yDEPVuxvIWrl2tElid..."
         |                |-- imageUri: ""
         |                |-- name: "Sahil"
         |                |-- password: "8zYQEN001zhQ7XZjzqHUnTIeCDIPvtI38Ra+X68a8/o=\n"
         |--CATEGORIES
               |--My_DATA
```

At present, I am using this rule for my firebase realtime database:

```json
    {
      "rules": {
        "USERS": {
        ".read": "auth != null",  // 2021-8-14
        ".write": "auth != null",  // 2021-8-14
        },
        "CATEGORIES":{
          ".read": "auth != null",
          ".write": "root.child('ADMIN').child('auth.uid').exists()",
        },
          "ADMIN": {
          ".read": true,
          ".write": true,
          }
      }
    }
```

my rule is giving always false condition even if I type a uid which exists in admin child.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote `auth.uid` as String. Try to change your rules to this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "USERS": {
    ".read": "auth != null",  // 2021-8-14
    ".write": "auth != null",  // 2021-8-14
    },
    "CATEGORIES":{
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "root.child('ADMIN').child(auth.uid).exists()",
                                        //     removed quotes
    },
      "ADMIN": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true,
      }
  }
}
```